# Why is String Stiffness Proportional to the Fourth Spatial Derivative of String Displacement?

Tags: waves, continuum-mechanics, dispersion

I recently watched a lecture on dispersive medium. I understand that if you disregard the idea that a string is ideal, you must add a stiffness factor into the wave equation. From that you can derive the equation $$ω/k = v\sqrt{1 + αk^2}$$ where $v$ is the speed of propagation. As a result, it is obvious that the speed is dependent on the wavenumber. What I don't understand is when the stiffness factor is added to the wave equation $$\partial^2{\psi}/{\partial{t^2}} = v^2[\partial^2{\psi}/\partial{x^2} - \alpha(\partial^4{\psi}/\partial{x^4})]$$ it shows up as the fourth derivative of string displacement. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a hand-waving argument, but string stiffness refers to the string's resistance to bending or curvature. Curvature is the second derivative of displacement, $\psi$, and therefore comes into the equation as d<sup>2</sup>{d<sup>2</sup>$\psi$/dx<sup>2</sup>}/dx<sup>2</sup> instead of d<sup>2</sup>$\psi$/dx<sup>2</sup>.